# Emacs - let-alist unavailable

Tags: emacs, emacs24

When I tried to install flycheck package on emacs24, it show error that let-alist1.0.1 unavailable. But I heard that let-alist is built-in package of emacs25, I wonder is there any work-around for emacs24?

Answer (score 1):

let-alist is available from ELPA. Use

```
M-x list-packages
```

to pull up a list of available packages, then search for `let-atlist` (`C-M-s` as usual). Then install it. See also [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA).

Alternatively, you can download it from [here](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/let-alist.html) and install it [manually](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_installing_packages.html). ELPA is easier, though.

Comment: Hi @Wintermute, I am using melpa, and it doesn't have let-alist package. Even when I add gnu elpa, it said cannot load from gnu elpa server.

Comment: Odd. I have `("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")` in my `package-archives`, and I have no trouble installing `let-alist` from there. But if it doesn't work for you, [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_installing_packages.html)'s a way to install packages manually.

Comment: Lol, that's really odd! Something's wrong with my internet or gnu server. It keeps contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80, never show up the list of packages.